# error when starting dev server npm run dev

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

so i was tinkering with laravel and i tried to install bootstrap. as soon as i need to type npm install && npm run dev, the install part goes with no hiccups. only when the run dev command this error shows up.

C:\Users\Enduser\Documents\laravel projects\sampleblog>npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> dev
> vite

error when starting dev server:

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:3000

```
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
at doListen (node:net:1559:7)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

any ideas on why this is happening? thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you're using Laravel 9, Vite is the default tool for bundling assets. You may want to roll back to webpack.mix by changing

> "development": "vite"

to

> "development": "mix"

in *package.json*, *script* section.

or in case of diving into this new feature, you can check Laravel documentation, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite).

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder C:\Program Files\nodejs

Open the file **npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd** in a text editor

Replace **prefix -g** with **prefix --location=global**

and try again with the same command.

```
npm run dev
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.